# If parabola with focus (2/5,4/5)...

Tags: conic-sections, coordinate-systems, tangent-line

so I was doing this question
[image: enter link description here]
And decided to go about it as shown below. Everything was going smooth until I came to eq. no 2 . here even though when we built the equation using all the correct things the eq 2 gives two roots where as it should have been a whole square in order to give us a single x-coordinate for A .
[image: enter link description here]
Secondly if you all think that there would be a better way to solve this question ,please share it . It will help me gain better and deeper knowledge.

Comment: There are non-guys on here too.

Comment: Why what's the issue in that

Comment: Your use of *guys* may alienate community members who do not identify as male.  For instance, women.

Comment: Oh sorry I thought you were reffering to me , I didn't mean to say it that way. Would certainly be careful next time

Comment: No worries, just something to think about.  It's easy to just delete the first two words of your post (as I see you've done!).

Comment: Why should the directrix  pass through origin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line tangent to a parabola at any point $P$ is the bisector of the angle formed by the line joining $P$ with the focus and by the perpendicular from $P$ to the directrix. In addition, the distance of $P$ from the focus is the same as he distance of $P$ from the directrix.

It follows that the reflections of focus $F$ about the coordinate axes: 
$H=(-2/5,4/5)$ and $K=(2/5,-4/5)$, are also the projections of tangency points on the directrix. Hence line $HK$ is the directrix and the lines from $H$ and $K$, perpendicular to the directrix, intersect y-axis and x-axis at tangency points $A=(0,1)$ and $B=(2,0)$.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a ton but can you please help me identify where I was going wrong in my explanation

Comment: Why should the directrix  pass through origin?

Comment: @DrZafarAhmedDSc Because line $HK$ passes through the origin. But there is also another reason: two perpendicular tangents to the same parabola always meet on the directrix.

Comment: @gucci You assumed the directrix to be perpendicular to $SO$, but that is not the case.

Comment: @Aretino oh that means I forcefully assumed $SO$ to be the axis even when it is just a random line, right?

Comment: @gucci Right, but it is not a random line: it is the reflection of the directrix about any one of the axes.

Comment: Oh Ok, thanks a lot @Aretino